# Location by IP for mobile user (python flask)

Tags: python, flask, geolocation, ip

I would like to find a users coarse location on the back end so that I can send it to an api and tell them the weather for their area. I do not want to use HTML 5 client side location requesting. I can use the python requests library to find a users public IP and send that to an IP geolocating. This works perfectly as expected on wifi connections. However when users are not connected to wifi the IP is associated with a location that is much farther away from the user. Now I know it is possible to get a users coarse location without permission on a mobile connection(such as googling "weather") I just don't know how to.

I found this and am reading it currently:
http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/maheshba/papers/ephemera-imc09.pdf

Comment: Why not just ask for permission to share their location through your web app?

Comment: For starters that is client side and I don't want to reload the page. Secondly I want to know how to do it on the back end because I know it is possible. Google does it when you google "weather" , then offers you the seperate option of permitting exact location and re-loading the result.